# Run a certain function according to a dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I built a script which runs a certain function according to a specific condition, the thing is I am sure there is a smarter way to do this.

The current code I have is:

```
list_of_dicts= [{'brand':'a', 'url':'b'}, [{'brand':'b', 'url':'b'}]

for element in list_of_dicts:
    if element['brand'] == 'a':
        function_a(element['url'])
    elif element['brand'] == 'b']:
        function_b(element['url'])
    else:
        None
```

Imagine I have instead of 2 brands, around 7, it's still feasible in this way, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: you can put function references in your dict. Like: `{'brand':'a', 'url':'b', 'function': function_a}`, and then: `element['function'](element['url'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate `dict` storing the functions from where you can then retrieve the appropriate function with brand:

```
list_of_dicts= [{'brand':'a', 'url':'b'}, {'brand':'b', 'url':'b'}]

def function_a(url):
    print('A ' + url)

def function_b(url):
    print('B ' + url)

funcs = {
    'a': function_a,
    'b': function_b
}

for element in list_of_dicts:
    func = funcs.get(element['brand'])
    if func:
        func(element['url'])
```

Output:

```
A b
B b
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects too (sorta...) and so you can just connect the `brand` key to a function like this:

```
list_of_dicts= [{'brand':function_a, 'url':'b'}, [{'brand':function_b, 'url':'b'}]
```

and then just grab the function with the key:

```
for element in list_of_dicts:
    element['brand'](element['url'])
```

Comment: Maybe its better to have another dict `brand_to_func = {'a': function_a, ...}` and then use `brand_to_func[element['brand']](...)`

Comment: @tobias_k, yes I agree (and apparently so do OP)